# Como enviar otra variable por medio de Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

un saludo.

No encuentro la forma de enviar dos variables al tiempo por medio de JavaScript y PHP.

Actualmente mi código funciona enviando una variable.

Este es el input.

```
<tr>
<?php
    require ('conexespecial/selectconex.php');
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT flota FROM para_equipo WHERE cliente='$acliente' ORDER BY flota";
    $resultado=$mysqli->query($query);
?>
    <td><font color="#000">Flota:</font></td>
    <td><select name="cbx_estado" id="cbx_estado" class="camp" required >
                <option></option>
                <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['flota']; ?>"><?php echo $row['flota']; ?></option>
                    
                <?php } ?>
                
<!--ADICIONAL A LA VARIABLE QUE YA ESTOY ENVIANDO AL SELECCIONAR EL SELECT TAMBIEN ESTOY BUSCANDO ENVIAR LA VARIABLE DE $acliente-->
<input type="hidden" name="clientec" value="<?php echo $acliente;?>" readonly="readonly">
            </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Este es el JavaScript en donde no se como hacer para enviar una segunda variable al mismo tiempo que el select.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#cbx_estado").change(function () {

                    $('#cbx_localidad').find('option').remove().end().append('<option value="whatever"></option>').val('whatever');
                    
                    $("#cbx_estado option:selected").each(function () {
                        flota = $(this).val();
                        $.post("conexespecial/getMunicipio.php", { flota: flota }, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_municipio").html(data);
                        });            
                    });
                })
            });
```

Y aquí es donde recibo la variable:

```
<?php
    require ('selectconex.php');
    
    $flota = $_POST['flota'];
    $clientec = $_POST['clientec'];
    
    $queryM = "SELECT DISTINCT nro_equipo FROM para_equipo WHERE flota = '$flota' AND cliente='$clientec' ORDER BY nro_equipo";
    $resultadoM = $mysqli->query($queryM);
    
    $html= "<option></option>";
    
    while($rowM = $resultadoM->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $html.= "<option value='".$rowM['nro_equipo']."'>".$rowM['nro_equipo']."</option>";
    }
    
    echo $html;
?>
```

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me puede ser de gran utilidad, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto te puede solucionar.
Al input hidden agrégale un ID o una CLASE

```
<input type="hidden" name="clientec" value="<?php echo $acliente;?>" readonly="readonly" id='cliente'>
```

y aquí agrégalo para extraer su valor

```
 $("#cbx_estado option:selected").each(function () {
                        flota = $(this).val(); cliente=$("#cliente").val()
```

y aquí lo agregas en el parámetro para que se agregue en el post

```
$.post("conexespecial/getMunicipio.php", { flota: flota , cliente:cliente}, function(data){
                            $("#cbx_municipio").html(data);
                        });
```

Comment: Hola Heyner me funciono perfecto, esa era la ayuda que necesitaba. muchas gracias.